# Java Handling TIF Images

Tags: java, image, tiff, javax.imageio

My question is, what how can I successfully load a .tif file into an Image instance in Java?

Let me give some more detail now. I have read a lot of the threads on stackoverflow on how to handle/convert TIF images in Java. I have tried a lot of the stackoverflow suggestions (I say suggestions, because rarely do the people asking come back and say something has worked for them). I am pretty sure I need to use the Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) library, but I don't think I know how to use it. Let me explain the project now:

I am taking screens of frames from a Processing sketch, and encoding them into video using Xuggler. In the sketch I use Processing's save(file filePath) function to save the current frame to a file. I used to have **save("img"+i+".jpg")**, but the compression that takes place when creating a jpg was slowing down the recording to 9-10fps, so I switched the file extension to see if I could get varying results, and **save("img"+i".tif")** was the fastest, allowing me to record at about 22-23fps.

Processing can save images as .tif files. Unfortunately though, Java cannot load .tif files back without a library. I used to have the code:
     **Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("pics/img"+i+".jpg");**
That line of code would load up the .jpg files into img and I'd be good to encode the video. But this line of code (tif instead of jpg):

     **Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("pics/img"+i+".tif");**
Will not load up any image. I am still able to encode my video with Xuggler, but the images are blank, so I think this method is not working to load my .tif files.

I am working on a Windows 8 computer, and using Eclipse. Any help will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need [JAI](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/iio-141084.html).

```
  import javax.media.jai.PlanarImage;
  import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ByteArraySeekableStream;
  import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageCodec;
  import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageDecoder;
  import com.sun.media.jai.codec.SeekableStream;
  import java.awt.Image;
  import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
...
  static Image load(byte[] data) throws Exception{
    Image image = null;
    SeekableStream stream = new ByteArraySeekableStream(data);
    String[] names = ImageCodec.getDecoderNames(stream);
    ImageDecoder dec = 
      ImageCodec.createImageDecoder(names[0], stream, null);
    RenderedImage im = dec.decodeAsRenderedImage();
    image = PlanarImage.wrapRenderedImage(im).getAsBufferedImage();
    return image;
  }
```

Comment: I now have JAI, I've built the paths, and I've written load(byte[] data). How do I use load(byte[] data)? I have the file path "pics/img"+i+".tif", how do I (if this is what I have to do) change that to type byte[]? Or what should I be putting in as the parameter? Thanks again.

Comment: Never mind, I figured out how to change a .tif file to an array of bytes. I'm encoding the video perfectly now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use JAI. I would recommend you use the normal ImageIO API and a TIFF plugin.

For Java 9 and later, a basic TIFF plugin is bundled with the JDK. For earlier versions, or if you need more advanced capabilities, there are several other TIFF plugins for ImageIO available, and depending on your needs, you could use the one from jai-imageio, my [TIFF plugin](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#aldusadobe-tagged-image-file-format-tiff) or some other third-party plugin.

My plugin supports most common types of TIFFs. In contrast to jai-imageio, no native libs are required. You can either add Maven dependencies to your project or download directly from [this link](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#links-to-prebuilt-binaries).

The good thing about using the ImageIO API, is that after you have the plugins properly installed, all you need to do is:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read("pics/img"+i+".tif");
```

Comment: Worked instantely after simply adding to the pom.xml (from Maven Central). Even with 16 bit TIFF images. Good work, thank you!